# Javascript call from code-behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager

I am using ScriptManager in asp.net page. And I can not working javascript code from c# code. I tried script manager,update panel... and did not solution. Or I can not.

I want to call javascript code in code-behind.

Code-Behind:

```
{
public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

     protected void btnGetir_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RunCMD();



    }

    public void RunCMD()
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFiles)
        {

            foreach (HttpPostedFile btnUpload in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
            {

                string ext = Path.GetExtension(btnUpload.FileName);

                if (ext == ".tab" || ext == ".TAB" || ext == ".kml" || ext == ".KML")
                {



                    string dosya = btnUpload.FileName;
                    string cmd = "cmd";
                    string enter = "/c";
                    string ad = dosya.Remove(dosya.Length - 4);

                    string exe =
                        " ogr2ogr -f \"GeoJSON\" -t_srs WGS84 " +
                        "C:\\json\\" + ad + ".json " +
                        "C:\\" + dosya;


                    try
                    {
                        Process p = new Process();
                        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(cmd, enter + exe);
                        p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                        p.Start();
                        p.WaitForExit();



                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }

                    string json = ReadJSON("C:\\json\\" + ad + ".json");




                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                        this,
                        this.GetType(),
                       "deneme",

                        "deserialize('" + json + "');",
                        true);


                }

                else
                {



                }


            }



        }
    }

    public string ReadJSON(string jsonPath)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(jsonPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        string WillReturn = "";

        try
        {
            WillReturn = sr.ReadToEnd();







            return WillReturn;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            WillReturn = null;
            return WillReturn;
        }
        finally { sr.Close(); fs.Dispose(); }


    }



}
}
```

in javascript code:

```
<script>
function deserialize(json) {

        // var element = document.getElementById('text');
        var type = document.getElementById("formatType").value;
        var features = formats['in'][type].read(json);
        var bounds;
        if (features) {
            if (features.constructor != Array) {
                features = [features];
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < features.length; ++i) {
                if (!bounds) {
                    bounds = features[i].geometry.getBounds();
                } else {
                    bounds.extend(features[i].geometry.getBounds());
                }

            }
            vectors.addFeatures(features);
            map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
            var plural = (features.length > 1) ? 's' : '';
            //element.value = features.length + ' feature' + plural + ' added';
        } else {
            //element.value = 'Bad input ' + type;
        }
    }
</script>
```

in html code:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnGetir" runat="server" OnClick="btnGetir_Click1" Text="Button" />
   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
```

deserialize function not working.
How can I succeed this ?

Comment: IMO this should work. Did you check if the execution is reaching the "ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript"? Also did you try and put just alert("hi"); as the first line in your javascript function just to make sure that the function is getting called or not in the first place? Also note that this function will get called only after the page lifecycle ends and not in between your execution of your button  code.

Comment: I tried only alert('hi'); its working. So         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
                        this,
                        this.GetType(),
                       "deneme",

                        "alert('hi');",
                        true);      its working.

Comment: What I meant was that the deserialize function should contain only alert("hi"); and nothing else and then call the function from C# code.